# Java Breaking up a String into multiple substrings

Tags: java

right now I am trying to break up a line into multiple pieces and have them take on multiple substrings.  My line will consist of about 10 strings that I wish to break up.  The first will be a string and the following sets of data will be numbers.  The first one I have broken apart easy enough, but as I advance downwards, I am finding multiple problems.

An example would be "Jack 5 2 12 31 1 2 111 1 2 3".

```
public static void histogram(String line)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    String l1 = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));
    int l1l = l1.length() + 2;
    String l2 = line.substring(l1l, line.indexOf(" "));
    System.out.print(l2);

}
```

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?  I am limited to using substrings and loops to accomplish this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `"Does anyone know how I can go about doing this? I am limited to using substrings and loops to accomplish this."` -- Then try to use subStrings and loops -- we don't see your attempt to do this yet, and this is a requirement for homework-type questions. Or at the very least ask a more specific question please.

Comment: Note -- you do know that the `indexOf(...)` is overloaded, and these might prove helpful to you.

Comment: Well, loops I'm indifferent to at this point, I can fancy up later.  I am using the indexOf, but the best I can figure is once I use it a second time around, it latches onto the first space and refuses to return that first set of numbers despite indexing it to say, index 4 + 1("Jack ").  It keeps saying I'm out of range.  So, if I could some how get past that one, I'd be fine and on my way.
Edit: And this has been with adjusting the int l1l right there multiple times, +1, +2, etc.

Comment: line.split(" ") will convert it to an Array

Comment: Never mind.  Figured it out.  An easier thing to do was to use the lastIndexOf() and from there create the new substring then delete it from the end of the substring and create a new one based.  Awesome.  Thanks anyways for the help.

     {
  System.out.println(line);
  String l1 = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" "), line.length());

  System.out.print(l1);
  String newStr;
  newStr = line.replace(l1, "");
  System.out.print(newStr);  
 }

Comment: @Vaak You may take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `split()` method of the String class. It is convenient in your case since all you want to do is split over a single space. The `split()` method return an array of Strings which you can then use for further processing. Find the documentation here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: `Why don't you use the split() ` because this is a homework from school and school gives restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the solution for your question is so short that once I tell you, it is already the answer. Anyway, this is how you can do it (since you can only use **for-loop** and **substring**):

```
int size = 11;   //Assume you know the size of number of tokens
String str = "Jack 5 2 12 31 1 2 111 1 2 3";
String[] ary = new String[size];

for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
    int idx = str.indexOf(" ");          //Get position of first space
    if(idx != -1){                       //If space exist
        ary[x] = str.substring(0, idx);  //Get the first token
        str = str.substring(idx+1);      //Remove the first token from string       
    }               
}
ary[size-1] = str;                       //Assign the last substring
```

- Basically, you always only need to read the first substring (i.e. Jack) according to the position of the first space.
- After you assigned it, remove it from the original string
- In next iteration, your first substring will be "5" since you already removed "Jack " from the original string.